# Parsing string and collecting the HTML elements with different id's

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have passed the HTML content to a string say"Html_content". I need to parse string "Html_content"  and pick few DIV tags using there ID's say for example "fullHeader" is id of the DIV, i need to pick the content which is inside the div tag of "fullHeader" and store it a string.

I tried [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org) but I need to save the collected div tags inside Document, But I need to save it as string, but its not possible using Jsoup, is there any alternative?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to reference the `div` elements from the html and put them into a collection of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSoup is exactly what you need. What I understood is that you need have the HTML elements returned to you in String form so that you can further use them to create another document.

suppose you have the Element object say *ele* extracted out from the HTML.

Now write

String htmlForEle = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div")).append(ele.clone()).remove().html();

html for ele is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> *But I need to save it as string, but its not possible using Jsoup*

Wrong, Jsoup has an [`Element#text()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29) method for this.

```
String text = element.text(); // <div>foo<b>bar</b></div> will give "foobar"
// ...
```

Or when you want to include the HTML in the string as well, use [`Element.html()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28%29) or [`Element#outerHtml()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#outerHtml%28%29), depending on the requirement.

```
String html = element.html(); // <div>foo<b>bar</b></div> will give "foo<b>bar</b>"
// ...
```

or

```
String html = element.outerHtml(); // <div>foo<b>bar</b></div> will give exact this string
// ...
```

Comment: thank you BalusC your answer has helped me a lot, its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

If you force your HTML to XML syntax then you can use XPath, SAX, DOM, and other XML tools to manipulate the document.